# How to find the date of each new occurrence of a value in R

Tags: r, date

I have a large dataset with a table of date/times and areas of occurrence for uniquely tagged animals:

date_time   Area    Tag ID
05/11/2010 13:27:33     1   A
*   2   B
*   2   B
*   2   A
*   3   B
*   3   A
*   1   A
*   2   B
*   2   A

-I'm not sure why my table keeps turning into a line....sorry

I would like to figure out the first occurrence (date/time) for each unique animal each time it enters a new area.

ie., first date/time in area 1, then the date/time when it enters area 2, date/time when it enters area 1 again and so on.

perhaps a loop could be used to cycle through all the tag IDs?

Thank-you for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

Using plyr::ddply, you could use the option 'summarize' on Tag ID and Area.
For instance, if your dataframe is called df, and date_time is in POSIXct,

```
summary<-ddply(df, .(Tag ID, Area), summarize,
         First.time = min(date_time)
```

Comment: Thanks! that is really close but it selects only the first time that a animal goes to a new area. If for instance the animal goes to area 2 and then to area 1 and then back to area 2 I need the date_time of the first occurrence every time this switch is observed.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. If you could find a way to categorize the Areas based on visits in a new column (for example, area1_1: 1st visit to area1, area1_2: 2nd visit to area1, etc) you could then just use ddply on that new column. Can you post a usable sample of your data? You can use the function dput() to create a publishable snippet of your dataset.

Comment: ok, for instance let's say i have a table of locations  (i.e., 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1) and each one of these locations has a time associated with it in a second column. I am looking for an output that would change that first table into one with a location column (i.e.,1,2,1,3,1) where each of these locations is the first occurrence at the new location with the associated date in a new column.

Comment: Yep, I got that part. What I'm suggesting is to have a new column in which each location/area is categorized by the number of time it's been used (i.e, **1_1, 1_1, 1_1, 1_1**, 2_1, 2_1, 2_1, **1_2, 1_2, 1_2**, 3_1, 3_1, 3_1, **1_3, 1_3**). It'd be useful if you could post some of your data in your question (not all of it, just a bit more than that column you just described).